# convertir lista en entero python y separar pares

Tags: python, stdin, stdout

comanda:

```
cat nums.txt | python3 prueba.py > nuevonums.txt
```

nums.txt:

```
1
2
7
8
```

Necesito editar `prueba.py` para que me tome estos números y los separe sus pares (2 y 8). Para esto habría que convertirlos a `int` verdad?

Quiero hacer

```
IF (nom %2 == 0): 
   pares[] 
else 
   impar[]
```

Lo que hice sólo toma la cadena de texto (`numeros`) y los envía tal cual.

```
import sys 
for nom in sys.stdin:
    nom = nom.strip()
    print(type(nom))
```

Comment: olvide decir, que los numeros tienen '\n\ salto de linea en nums.txt .

Answer (score 1):

esto separa los numeros, los convierte a enteros, los procesa en variables separaadas aquellas que su residuo no es 0 y los convierte a string nuevamente para enviarlos a sus respectivos destinos.

```
import sys
contador= 0
contador_imp= 0
for nom in sys.stdin:
    nom = int(nom.strip('\n'))
    if nom % 2 == 0:
        par=nom
        sys.stdout.write(str(par)+ '\n')
        contador+=1        
    else: 
        impar= nom
        sys.stderr.write(str(impar) + '\n')
        contador_imp+=1
sys.stdout.write('hay ' + str(contador)+ ' numeros pares' )
sys.stderr.write('hay ' + str(contador_imp) + ' numeros impares')
```